# Is it OK to show google map API without actually showing a map?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I would like to use google map API to get a map canvas to put objects on it, but not showing the map, by using the maptype NONE.
Am I allowed to do that in an Android app using v2 and distribute it?

This is what I want to do:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

        // Other supported types include: MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
        // MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID and MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    }
```

I want to set map.setMapType(**GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE**); and then add various markers to the map, including my current position

Added a picture to show what I want to achieve.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) it's forbidden. More over - From what you are saying it seems that you want use gmaps capabilities to get data and calculations but actually display some thing else. I really don't think it's good idea. However - if the issue is making geo calculations, consider to use 3'rd party open source libs for this. For example http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula-java/

Comment: Can you please provide a link where it says it is forbidden?

Comment: I want to show current location using the location manager, and other symbols on map. But to decrease the amount of data transferred to an absolute minimum, I want to show a blank map.
Edit: Of course, if data transfer is no (money) issue, and reception is good, a satellite or normal map can be shown. this is just to be able to provide a solution when the conditions for cunsuming lots of data are poor.

Comment: If you just want to use the location manager, you can do it without the Maps API. CMIIW

Comment: @Magnus I added a link I'm pretty sure it's said there

Comment: I doubt it's forbidden, why else would the API allow it. However I'm not a lawyer and that's too much text for me to read ;)

Comment: @Wilik No I want to show objects on their correct positions, and the users current position, to make it possible to navigate to them, but without knowing the shortest path by looking at the map to be able to avoid dead ends, rivers, lakes, railways etc that is not possible to pass. Just a blank map.

Comment: @michael I've read that documentation but been able to find the portion of  text that says that it not permitted to use a google map using map type NONE. Can you point out the paragraphs as well?

Comment: In the developer documentation example this could be found (Sorry for bad format :( )



   `map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

        // Other supported types include: MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
        // MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID and **MAP_TYPE_NONE**
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`

Comment: @Magnus The point (and the real interesting thing in that context) is what you do display relative to the points (locations) you used Google to get them? If you overlay the `MAP_TYPE_NONE` with some other kind of map - this is forbidden. If you really use just `MAP_TYPE_NONE` so I guess according to the comment you gave it seems OK. Any way you can raise question to maps support they are responsive.

Comment: @michael I added some code to my original post for clarification (i hope).
I've tried to ask them the same direct question, but only got references to the documentation without answering my question... But yes, agree, they are at least responsive!

Comment: @Magnus It's better to see a picture of the resulted UI - let's say if I find there some custom map you build or open street map anything like this, so we have an issue because earlier you used Gmaps to retrieve geo locations etc.

Comment: @michael Sure, can add a picture later when able to provide one. But no, just the plain gray background, no map info at all, just markers added, and the coordinates is pointing at various locations that I have come up with myself, stored as lat/lng. Thats why I need a google map to display them, but do not want to show the data consuming map data.
It is in fact a game...

Comment: @michael picture added. To be able to draw for example plygons on a canvas by by adding LatLng position to a google map that does not display map data.